# Tabularray Can't adjust vertical space

Tags: tabularray, baseline

I'm creating a longtblr, using the package tabularray. When trying to reduce the vertical space, using `rowsep = 0pt` it better, but not the same as a normal table.

Here is an MW:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % interlineado de 1.5
    
\usepackage{multirow, array} % Opciones para trabajar con tablas
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{Continuación en la siguiente página}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{(Continuación)}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[]{
        colspec = {Q[c,3.2cm]Q[c,3.2cm]Q[c,2cm]Q[c,3cm]},
        rowhead = 1,
        rowsep = 0pt,
    }
    \toprule
    Dato 1 & Dato 2 & Dato 3 & Dato 4\\
    29/04/23 09:30 & 29/04/23 23:00 & 13,50 & 41,92 \\
    19/03/23 01:00 & 19/03/23 02:22 & 1,37 & 51,47 \\
    26/01/23 15:00 & 26/01/23 15:29 & 0,48 & 70,34 \\
    17/11/22 07:15 & 17/11/22 19:00 & 11,75 & 23,29 \\
    25/10/22 12:01 & 25/10/22 19:45 & 7,73 & 104,42 \\
    13/07/22 09:35 & 13/07/22 10:22 & 0,78 & 77,76 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{C{3.2cm}C{3.2cm}C{2cm}C{3cm}}
        Dato 1 & Dato 2 & Dato 3 & Dato 4\\
        29/04/23 09:30 & 29/04/23 23:00 & 13,50 & 41,92 \\
        19/03/23 01:00 & 19/03/23 02:22 & 1,37 & 51,47 \\
        26/01/23 15:00 & 26/01/23 15:29 & 0,48 & 70,34 \\
        17/11/22 07:15 & 17/11/22 19:00 & 11,75 & 23,29 \\
        25/10/22 12:01 & 25/10/22 19:45 & 7,73 & 104,42 \\
        13/07/22 09:35 & 13/07/22 10:22 & 0,78 & 77,76 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

When removing `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % interlineado de 1.5`, it “get solved” but I need it for the rest of the document.

How can I set the vertical distance to 0?

Here is an image of the output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table can be write also on the following way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % interlineado de 1.5

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{Continuación en la siguiente página}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{(Continuación)}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Caption title},      
  label = {tab:??}         
                ]{stretch=0,    % <---
                  colspec = {c c Q[c,si={table-format=2.2}] Q[c,si={table-format=3.2}]},
                  row{1}  = {guard},
                  rowhead = 1,     
                  }
    \toprule
Dato 1          & Dato 2            & Dato 3& Dato 4 \\
    \midrule
29/04/23 09:30  & 29/04/23 23:00    & 13,50 &  41,92 \\
19/03/23 01:00  & 19/03/23 02:22    &  1,37 &  51,47 \\
26/01/23 15:00  & 26/01/23 15:29    &  0,48 &  70,34 \\
17/11/22 07:15  & 17/11/22 19:00    & 11,75 &  23,29 \\
25/10/22 12:01  & 25/10/22 19:45    &  7,73 & 104,42 \\
13/07/22 09:35  & 13/07/22 10:22    &  0,78 &  77,76 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! 'stretch=0' was the code I was missing!! Also liked the way numbers align at decimal.

Comment: What does {guard} and si={table-format=2.2} does?

Comment: @JJP, `guard` protect row against `S` column` formatting (similar as to ˙{<cell text>}` in standard tables. I strongly suggest you to read `tabularray` package documentation again- Also be aware, that it is still in development and it is updated (together with its documentation) two to three times per year :-)

Answer (score 1):

Founded a workaround. `\begin{spacing}{1} … \end{spacing}` do the work just fine.

Here is how the table ended:

```
\begin{spacing}{1}
    \begin{longtblr}[]{
            colspec = {Q[c,3.2cm]Q[c,3.2cm]Q[c,2cm]Q[c,3cm]},
            rowhead = 1,
            rowsep = 0pt,
        }
        \toprule
        Dato 1 & Dato 2 & Dato 3 & Dato 4\\
        29/04/23 09:30 & 29/04/23 23:00 & 13,50 & 41,92 \\
        19/03/23 01:00 & 19/03/23 02:22 & 1,37 & 51,47 \\
        26/01/23 15:00 & 26/01/23 15:29 & 0,48 & 70,34 \\
        17/11/22 07:15 & 17/11/22 19:00 & 11,75 & 23,29 \\
        25/10/22 12:01 & 25/10/22 19:45 & 7,73 & 104,42 \\
        13/07/22 09:35 & 13/07/22 10:22 & 0,78 & 77,76 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\end{spacing}
```